# Windows 10 Mail does not obey "Reply-To:"

Tags: email, windows-mail

I use Windows 10 Mail (the built-in Mail app) with an outlook.com e-mail account. For some reasons, it does not obey the Reply-To: field of an e-mail.

To add insult to injury, when I reply. I will see the `To:` address as `John Doe johndoe@gmail.com [XYZ]`. But the e-mail is actually `XYZ-noreply@yahoogroups.com` and I only found out later that the e-mail got bounced back.

The problem does not happen when replying from outlook.com. I want to use the built-in mail app because it works offline. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: We ran into this issue as well. The answer is that the Windows 10 Mail app is broken and stupid. Apparently there is a "Windows insider" report for this ([found here](https://community.canvaslms.com/thread/11144#comment-52801)) but that's not publicly accessible. In the meanwhile all we can do is wait and hope Microsoft fixes their crap, but considering this is a known problem [for well over a year](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-outlook_mail/mails-not-being-sent-to-email-defined-in-reply-to/e5ac830c-7391-471d-9839-e46f5bde4b70) I'm not holding my breath

Comment: After 2 major updates of Windows 10 the problem still exist on May 17 2017